# How to put a text-interface based on system.out.print on a GUI? - JAVA -

Tags: java, user-interface, text, graphic, windowbuilder

I did a project for university (it is a personal implementation of Zork the Game). As asked I did it with a text interface, using system.out.print. Is there a way to "put the text interface in a GUI" ? I mean for example a simple window with 2 fields, one that displays text output and one for the text input by keyboard.

I downloaded windowsBuilder for eclipse but.. I dont know what to do! :(

Thanks!

Comment: for your second question you can add `KeyListener` and append pushed keys into `JTextArea` for example.

Comment: You're asking us to write your program for you.  What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: @Jim Barrows If I create a window with WindowBuilder I only find ways to create a static text field. I would like to get the "consecutive" text that I have in the terminal when I run my app, and a field where putting the input (is like the terminal itself, but more cute, for example with colored text)

Comment: Yes you can, it's quite easy, you want to look up Swing, and probably `JFrame`, `JTextArea` and `JTextField`. Check out the tutorials for more info http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is, just change the output stream for System class. Create a PrintStream that will write out your data to your swing components and then replace it in the System class to use it.

```
System.setOut(printStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this for a text game, I'd recommend using a [Glk](http://www.eblong.com/zarf/glk/) library. Glk is a cross-platform windowing I/O system designed for text games. You may have to write a JNI interface since the libraries tend to be written in C: an existing project called [GlkJNI](http://code.google.com/p/glkjni/) is meant to work the other way around, so a C program can use a Java UI, but it might be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of how to create a GUI that does what you are asking, take a look at this article: http://www.comweb.nl/java/Console/Console.html

This does *not* use best practices for building a GUI, but for quick and dirty, it'll get you started.  You really should read up on how to properly write a Swing application, though, if this is going to be something you are serious about.